# Visual Studio SDK - How to create a window similar to the one with breakpoint settings?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

How can I create a window appearing in the code editor window like this one in an extension:

[image: breakpoint settings window]

Answer (score 1):

Internally the code is using [IPeekBroker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.ipeekbroker.aspx) to create peek sessions which contain the UI. It uses a [IPeekResultPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.ipeekresultpresenter.aspx) to specify the UI.

As best I can tell these APIs are documented but there's no sample out there of how to use them. I'll send some emails to the relevant teams.

Comment: Thank you, it would be very helpful to see some samples.

Comment: @JakubBielawa, we are working on a full end to end custom Peek sample, I expect it to be published very soon. I'll update this question with a link once it's available.

Comment: @OlegTkachenko, that's great! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it took longer than I expected, but here is a full end to end real world example of a custom content (WPF browser control in this case) hosted in a Peek window: https://github.com/Microsoft/VS-PPT/tree/master/src/PeekF1/src. This is how breakpoint settings window is implemented.